# Adding a second database table to a query and outputting a column that has the same name as another

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following query below and I am having a hard time figuring out the best way to add in a database table to it. I want to be able to add the table `forum_categories` to it and just select the `id` from that. I'm not sure how to have two of the same column names in a query, but that is the only field I need from that table.

How can I add `forum_categories` to this query..

```
$query2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM forum_topics ORDER BY topic_reply_date DESC LIMIT 3")
```

And then fetch only the id from it and be able to output it with having the same column name?

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
    $query2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM forum_topics ORDER BY topic_reply_date DESC LIMIT 3")
    or die ("Query2 failed: %s\n".($query2->error));
    $numrows2 = mysqli_num_rows($query2);
    if($numrows2 > 0){
    $topics .= "<table width='100%' style='border-collapse: collapse;'>";
    //Change link once discussion page is made
    $topics .= "<tr style='background-color: #dddddd;'><td>Topic Title</td><td width='65' align='center'>Replies</td><td width='65' 
    align='center'>Views</td></tr>";
    $topics .= "<tr><td colspan='3'><hr /></td></tr>";
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)){
        $tid = $row2['id'];
        $title = $row2['topic_title'];
        $views = $row2['topic_views'];
        $date = $row2['topic_date'];
        $creator = $row2['topic_creator'];
        $topics .= "<tr><td><a href='forum_view_topic.php?tid=".$tid."'>".$title."</a><br /><span class='post_info'>Posted 
        by: ".$creator." on ".$date."</span></td><td align='cener'>0</td><td align='center'>".$views."</td></tr>";
        $topics .= "<tr><td colspan='3'><hr /></td></tr>";
    }
    $topics .="</table>";
    echo $topics;
    } else {
    echo "<p>There are no topics in this category yet.</p>";
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: To have two column names that are the same in a query use an ALIAS or `table.column`

Comment: Try `SELECT t.*, c.id AS cid FROM forum_topics AS t, forum_categories AS c ORDER BY t.topic_reply_date DESC LIMIT 3`.

Comment: That worker perfect! Convert your comment into the answer and I will award it to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your corrected SQL query:

```
SELECT t.*, c.id AS cid FROM forum_topics AS t, forum_categories AS c ORDER BY t.topic_reply_date DESC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help!